# Haskeline: Implementing `MonadException` instance for `ReaderT r (StateT s m)` stack

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have the following monad transformer stack (`r` and `s` left as `()` for simplicity),

```hs
newtype MyMonad m a = MM (ReaderT () (StateT () m a)
```

If I want to use this as a base monad for haskeline's `InputT`, I need a `System.Console.Haskeline.MonadException` instance. Given the [apparent complexity](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskeline/0.7.0.3/doc/html/src/System-Console-Haskeline-MonadException.html) of these instances, I'd prefer to let the compiler derive this for me with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`. Specifically, I would expect the following to typecheck,

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, StandaloneDeriving, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Applicative
import System.Console.Haskeline.MonadException

newtype MyMonad m a = MM (ReaderT () (StateT () m) a)
                    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
deriving instance (MonadException m) => MonadException (MyMonad m)
```

Yet sadly, this gives me,

```
/home/bgamari/hi.hs:11:1:
    Could not deduce (MonadException (StateT () m))
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    from the context (MonadIO (MyMonad m), MonadException m)
      bound by the instance declaration at /home/bgamari/hi.hs:11:1-66
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (MonadException (StateT () m))
    In the instance declaration for `MonadException (MyMonad m)'
```

Looking at the provided instances for `StateT` and `ReaderT`,

```hs
instance MonadException m => MonadException (ReaderT r m)
instance MonadException m => MonadException (StateT s m)
```

it seems perfectly reasonable to expect the compiler to deduce the `StateT` instance. Am I expecting too much of cunning `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`? How is one to implement this instance short of open-coding it?

Answer (score 5):

There are two versions of the State monad: [strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Strict.html) and [lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html). `import Control.Monad.State` [brings in the lazy version](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-State.html), but the instance of `MonadException` seems to be for the strict version.

Try with `import Control.Monad.State.Strict` instead of `import Control.Monad.State`.

Comment: Yep, it seems you are right. I think this actually makes this question a duplicate of Question #16944016